# How to handle caching while timing an operating in C++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, caching, profiling, timing

I have to time the clock_gettime() function for estimating and profiling other operations, and it's for homework so I cant use a profiler and have to write my own code.

The way I'm doing it is like below:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&begin);

for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);

cout<<(end.tv_nsec-begin.tv_nsec)/n; //time per clock_gettime()
```

The problem is that when n=100, output is: 370.63 ns, when n=100000, output: 330 ns, when n=1000000, output: 260 ns, n=10000000, output: 55 ns, ....keeps reducing.

I understand that this is happening because of instruction caching, but I don't know how to handle this in profiling. Because for example when I estimate the time for a function call using gettime, how would I know how much time that gettime used for itself?

Would taking a weighted mean of all these values be a good idea? (I can run the operation I want the same number of times, take weighted mean of that, subtract weighted mean of gettime and get a good estimate of the operation irrespective of caching?)

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, whenever you call clock_gettime() to profile other stuff it wont be cached (usually?), so an out-of-context call is fine for profiling other things... If i make myself clear.

Comment: Good point. Any idea how I can disable instruction caching to  time  get_time without any caching? Just using the values for low n's would not be a great idea I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compute the time difference: `(end.tv_nsec-begin.tv_nsec)/n`

You are only taking into account the nanoseconds part of the elapsed time. You must also take the seconds into account since the `tv_nsec` field only reflects the fractional part of a second:

```
int64_t end_ns = ((int64_t)end.tv_sec * 1000000000) + end.tv_nsec;
int64_t begin_ns = ((int64_t)begin.tv_sec * 1000000000) + begin.tv_nsec;
int64_t elapsed_ns = end_ns - begin_ns;
```

Actually, with your current code you should sometimes get negative results when the nanoseconds part of `end` has wrapped around and is less than `begin`'s nanoseconds part.

Fix that, and you'll be able to observe much more consistent results.

---

**Edit:** for the sake of completeness, here's the code I used for my tests, which gets me very consistent results (between 280 and 300ns per call, whatever number of iterations I use):

```
int main() {
  const int loops = 100000000;

  struct timespec begin;
  struct timespec end;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &begin);

  for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end);

  int64_t end_ns = ((int64_t)end.tv_sec * 1000000000) + end.tv_nsec;
  int64_t begin_ns = ((int64_t)begin.tv_sec * 1000000000) + begin.tv_nsec;
  int64_t elapsed_ns = end_ns - begin_ns;
  int64_t ns_per_call = elapsed_ns / loops;
  std::cout << ns_per_call << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The nanoseconds field will not wrap around, the size of int_64 is: 2^64-1, which is about 1.8 x 10^19. So the number of seconds after which nanoseconds will wrap around will be (1.8x10^19)/(10^9) ~ 10^10 seconds. No issues there.
Thank you for reminding me about taking seconds into account, that was a blunder. I was assuming seconds and nanoseconds fields are independent.

Comment: Btw, results look like this now: n=100, time: 374ns, n=10000, time: 363ns, n=100,000 time: 241ns, n=10,00,000 time: 153ns, n=1,00,00,000 time: 135ns, increasing n further it remains around 135 (fully cached?)

Comment: What I mean with "wrap around" is that `tv_nsec` is limited to values between 0 and 999999999 (10^9 - 1). When a full second elapses, `tv_sec` is incremented and `tv_nsec` goes back to zero. So, yes, you can have `end.tv_nsec < begin.tv_nsec` which would give you a negative value in your original computation. As to the timings evolving from 375ns to 135ns depending on the number of iterations, I can't reproduce that once I use the fix in my answer: I get consistent results around 280-300ns no matter the number of iterations.

Comment: I added the code I used so you can compare with yours. Again, this gives me very consistent results, far from what you observe.

Comment: This is weird. Even running your code as it is, I get values: 131 or 132 ns. When I reduce n to 100,000 in your code, I get around 250.

Comment: Well there are many variables possibly affecting those timings. Usual suspects are the processor (mine is a 2yo AMD) and the kernel version (3.9 on Debian Jessie). But even then I have to admit I am surprised there is so much discrepancy between your various measurements.

Comment: I am running it on my laptop, i7 1st gen, ubuntu 11.04. I am surprised that you are not experiencing decrease in time followed by saturation with increase in number of iterations like me. It feels "natural" that that should happen because of caching.

Comment: Sure caching is to be expected, but not so dramatically as the results you're seeing, IMHO. Since it's a very tight loop that does nothing but call `clock_gettime` the first iterations (and really, I mean like 50 at most) should be enough to stabilize the cache, no need to wait until you ran 10 million loops... FWIW I get much higher timings with 10 iterations (400ns) or 5 iterations (500ns) -- which is to be expected, and is unreliable anyway -- but it stabilizes starting at 20 iterations, around my "normal" timings ie. 280-300ns.

Comment: Note, one thing I just thought about is the global charge of your machine when you do the tests. I for one always take care to have nothing running in the background (I take care to put the machine in a position where it uses like 1% CPU if I don't launch a program myself). More background CPU usage would mean more cache trashing, thus increased timings on your benchmark. Just thinking out loud... :)

Comment: Makes sense. I have to admit, I had a ton of stuff open in the background which was stupid on my part. But I restarted my laptop, only opened the terminal and ran your program, still got the same results. This is weird and interesting at the same time.

Comment: Also, time reduces in a pretty uniform way as if more and more is being cached (except from 50k to 80k maybe) n=10k, time:365 | n=50k, time: 350 | n=80k, time:280| n=100k, time: 240 | n=500k, time: 155 | n=800k, time: 145 | n=1000k, time: 143 | n=5000k, time: 135 | n=8000k, time: 133.....then doesn't go below that.

Comment: Just curious, what kernel version are you running (`uname -a`)? April 2011 seems quite far away, the kernel has undergone many improvements since. Or maybe I'm totally mistaken and it's just the processor's behaviour that explains those differences.

Comment: uname -a output:
Linux shitij 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Well as far as I remember 2.6.39 was the beginning of a big overhaul (elimination of the so-called "big kernel lock") so yours predates those enhancements. Dunno if it's related though, I don't have anything to test against. If you really want to make sure, you might want to install a dual-boot with a more recent kernel (the closer to 3.9 you get, the more sure you'll be). This would allow you to see whether it's a software or hardware issue.

Comment: Hmmm. I already have a dual boot with windows and have very little space on my laptop. So that won't work. Btw, I made a program to plot the times and the time stabilises at about 3000 iterations. Thanks a lot for all the help, syam! :D